# SELECT query that displays the name of each record once and the count of instances

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible to write a SELECT query that displays the name of each record once and the count of how many instances of that record there are for certain criteria?

**For example, If I have a table with the following records:**

[image]

**How can I get the SELECT query to display the following:**

[image]

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation!

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Comment: To be fair, if it wasn't possible, the utility of sql would be quite limited

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
       sum( status = 'Disposed' ) as num_disposed,
       sum( status = 'Transported' ) as num_transported
from t
group by customer;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions like integers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, just adding up the boolean is a simple way to count the number of rows that match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a group by on case ansum for case

```
 select customer, sum(case when status ='disposed' then 1 else 0 end) count_disposed 
        sum(case when status ='trasposed' then 1 else 0 end) count_trasposed 
from my_table 
group by customer
```